# android: create circular image with picasso

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, picasso

The question had been asked and there had been a promise made for the very version of Picasso that I am using: How do I send a circular bitmap to an ImageView using Picasso? I am new to Picasso and only thing I have used is

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url).resize(w, h).into(imageview);
```

I have already found https://gist.github.com/julianshen/5829333 but I am not sure how to combine it with the line above in a non-awkward way.

Comment: The link you gave was enough to answer your own question. And you only needed to apply
         Picasso.with(activity).load(mayorShipImageLink).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(ImageView);

Answer (score 300, accepted):

Research a bit before as there are answers available. Anyhow, follow [This Link](https://gist.github.com/aprock/6213395) and read it carefully to know how to use it.

try this:

```
import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;

public class CircleTransform implements Transformation {
    @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
        int size = Math.min(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight());

        int x = (source.getWidth() - size) / 2;
        int y = (source.getHeight() - size) / 2;

        Bitmap squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size);
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            source.recycle();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(squaredBitmap,
                Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);

        float r = size / 2f;
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint);

        squaredBitmap.recycle();
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    public String key() {
        return "circle";
    }
}
```

then simply apply it like:

```
Picasso.with(activity).load(mayorShipImageLink).transform(new CircleTransform()).into(ImageView);
```

Comment: @anirudh-sharma

make sure to add these imports:

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;

import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;

Comment: @all: If you get into a null pointer exception on gif images, [check this](https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/997)

Comment: Works like a charm in Kotlin as well. One change for the existing APIs, `BitmapShader.TileMode.CLAMP` is not exsting anymore, I have  updated the answer

Comment: **DOES NOT WORK!** _Potential Fatal signal 6 (SIGBART)_, meaning that the bitmap.recycle() is actually removing the refrence from memory and causing an `signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
11-12 00:03:47.941 29091 29091 F DEBUG   : Abort message: 'Error, cannot access an invalid/free'd bitmap here!'` -> **Abort message: 'Error, cannot access an invalid/free'd bitmap here!** because it's garbage collected away from memory. `bitmap.recycle` is used for older Android devices, is what i understand.

Answer (score 55):

here is something that's provided by the **support-v4 library**! Look into 
[RoundedBitmapDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawable.html). No need to roll your own:

```
Picasso.with(context).load(url)
                        .resize(w, h)
                        .into(myImageView, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess() {
                                Bitmap imageBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) myImageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                                RoundedBitmapDrawable imageDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), imageBitmap);
                                imageDrawable.setCircular(true);
                                imageDrawable.setCornerRadius(Math.max(imageBitmap.getWidth(), imageBitmap.getHeight()) / 2.0f);
                                myImageView.setImageDrawable(imageDrawable);
                            }
                            @Override
                            public void onError() {
                                myImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_image);
                            }
                        });
```

Note: Picasso also has a *.transform(customTransformation)* call that you could theoretically use, however, I had issues with that. This above works. Good luck!

Comment: This will perfectly work for square image. Use Math.min in corner radius for any image. imageDrawable.setCornerRadius(Math.min(imageBitmap.getWidth(), imageBitmap.getHeight()) / 2.0f);

Comment: Shouldnt we create separate thread in OnSuccess(), because it can be long task to create Rounded bitmap from origin bitmap?

Answer (score 34):

There is a transformation library for Picasso.

Just add gradle dependency

```
implementation 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.4.0'
```

End use it

```
Picasso.with(context)
       .load(url)
       .resize(w, h)
       .transform(new CropCircleTransformation())
       .into(imageview);
```

Wiki: [Picasso Transformations](https://github.com/wasabeef/picasso-transformations)

Comment: This is really the perfect answer for this question, how come it has so little votes..

Answer (score 19):

Another alternative I found was this guys library. It works standalone, or in conjunction with Picasso. I chose the Picasso route, like below:

https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView

```
Transformation transformation = new RoundedTransformationBuilder()
          .borderColor(Color.BLACK)
          .borderWidthDp(3)
          .cornerRadiusDp(30)
          .oval(false)
          .build();

Picasso.with(context)
    .load(url)
    .fit()
    .transform(transformation)
    .into(imageView);
```

Worked for me!

Answer (score 10):

I have tried all solutions above but none of them gives me circle transform without cropping picture..those solution will work only for images with same width and height..this is my solution on above

first ------

```
Picasso.with(getActivity())
            .load(url)
            .error(R.drawable.image2)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_drawer)
            .resize(200, 200)
            .transform(new ImageTrans_CircleTransform())
            .into(imageView1);
```

then do this --------

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapShader;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Shader.TileMode;

import com.squareup.picasso.Transformation;
public class ImageTrans_CircleTransform implements Transformation {
 @Override
    public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
 if (source == null || source.isRecycled()) {
                return null;
            }

            final int width = source.getWidth() + borderwidth;
            final int height = source.getHeight() + borderwidth;

            Bitmap canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(source, TileMode.CLAMP, TileMode.CLAMP);
            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setShader(shader);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
            float radius = width > height ? ((float) height) / 2f : ((float) width) / 2f;
            canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius, paint);

            //border code
            paint.setShader(null);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setColor(bordercolor);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(borderwidth);
            canvas.drawCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius - borderwidth / 2, paint);
            //--------------------------------------

            if (canvasBitmap != source) {
                source.recycle();
            }

            return canvasBitmap;
}
 @Override
    public String key() {
        return "circle";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use this library to create a circular imageview.
[To make a circular ImageView, add this CircularImageView library to your project](https://github.com/Pkmmte/CircularImageView)
and add CircularImageView in your layout XML

```
<com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        app:border_color="#EEEEEE"
        app:border_width="4dp"
        app:shadow="true" />`
```

Then use picasso to load required image into this imageView. Picasso does all the caching you dont need to worry about it

Answer (score 2):

Include the xml drawable of type Layer- list with the code below

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/shape_status">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_status_content"/></layer-list>
```

then use the xml to your ImageView in the android.src

```
 <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iconStatus"
            android:layout_width="55dp"
            android:layout_height="55dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_circle_status"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Anirudh Sharma has a great answer.  This is his answer translated to Kotlin.

```
class CircleTransform : Transformation {
    override fun transform(source: Bitmap): Bitmap {
        val size = Math.min(source.width, source.height)
        val x = (source.width - size) / 2
        val y = (source.height - size) / 2
        val squaredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, x, y, size, size)
        if (squaredBitmap != source) {
            source.recycle()
        }
        val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, source.config)
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        val paint = Paint()
        val shader = BitmapShader(
            squaredBitmap,
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP
        )
        paint.shader = shader
        paint.isAntiAlias = true
        val r = size / 2f
        canvas.drawCircle(r, r, r, paint)
        squaredBitmap.recycle()
        return bitmap
    }

    override fun key(): String {
        return "circle"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is working with the current Picasso 3 snapshot:

```
class CircleTransformation : Transformation {

  override fun transform(source: RequestHandler.Result): RequestHandler.Result {
    if (source.bitmap == null) {
      return source
    }

    var bitmap: Bitmap

    // since we cant transform hardware bitmaps create a software copy first
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.O && source.bitmap!!.config == Config.HARDWARE) {
      val softwareCopy = source.bitmap!!.copy(Config.ARGB_8888, true)
      if (softwareCopy == null) {
        return source
      } else {
        bitmap = softwareCopy
        source.bitmap!!.recycle()
      }
    } else {
      bitmap = source.bitmap!!
    }

    var size = bitmap.width
    // if bitmap is non-square first create square one
    if (size != bitmap.height) {
      var sizeX = size
      var sizeY = bitmap.height
      size = Math.min(sizeY, sizeX)
      sizeX = (sizeX - size) / 2
      sizeY = (sizeY - size) / 2

      val squareSource = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, sizeX, sizeY, size, size)
      bitmap.recycle()
      bitmap = squareSource
    }

    val circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(circleBitmap)
    val paint = Paint()
    val shader = BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP)

    paint.shader = shader
    paint.isAntiAlias = true
    val centerAndRadius = size / 2f
    canvas.drawCircle(centerAndRadius, centerAndRadius, centerAndRadius, paint)

    bitmap.recycle()
    return RequestHandler.Result(circleBitmap, source.loadedFrom, source.exifRotation)
  }

  override fun key(): String {
    return "circleTransformation()"
  }
}
```

Picasso3 gist: https://gist.github.com/G00fY2/f3fbc468570024930c1fd9eb4cec85a1

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me with Picasso v2.71828

```
class CircleTransform : Transformation {
override fun transform(source: Bitmap?): Bitmap? {
    if (source == null) {
        return source
    }

    var bitmap: Bitmap

    // since we cant transform hardware bitmaps create a software copy first
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O && source.config == Bitmap.Config.HARDWARE) {
        val softwareCopy = source.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
        if (softwareCopy == null) {
            return source
        } else {
            bitmap = softwareCopy
            source.recycle()
        }
    } else {
        bitmap = source
    }

    var size = bitmap.width
    // if bitmap is non-square first create square one
    if (size != bitmap.height) {
        var sizeX = size
        var sizeY = bitmap.height
        size = Math.min(sizeY, sizeX)
        sizeX = (sizeX - size) / 2
        sizeY = (sizeY - size) / 2

        val squareSource = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, sizeX, sizeY, size, size)
        bitmap.recycle()
        bitmap = squareSource
    }

    val circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(size, size, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(circleBitmap)
    val paint = Paint()
    val shader = BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP)

    paint.shader = shader
    paint.isAntiAlias = true
    val centerAndRadius = size / 2f
    canvas.drawCircle(centerAndRadius, centerAndRadius, centerAndRadius, paint)

    bitmap.recycle()
    return circleBitmap
}


override fun key(): String {
    return "circleTransformation()"
}
```

}