# Circular layout with ImageViews

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to make circular layout, containing 4 square ImageViews. I need to set rounded border to the whole layout, so every ImageView must be rounded in one corner.
It must look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuJ5q.jpg

How can I do this?
I'm loading pictures from the network using Picasso library

Comment: if background it always some ,just add a picture has a circle hole to cover them.

Comment: unfortunately, background is not static

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem.
I am combining 4 bitmaps in one and set this bitmap as source in [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView).
Example of combining bitmaps I found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15152221/4974127) SO answer.

Comment: Operating bitamps is dangerous!

Comment: @tinysunlight I agree, but in my case bitmaps size is around 100x100 pixels, so I hope it will not trigger OutOfMemoryException :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112150/android-create-circular-image-with-picasso)

to create circular image view in picasso and for combining 4 images try using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739971/overlay-two-images-in-android-to-set-an-imageview)

Answer (score 0):

I think that can help you !

https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview.

It help you product imageview with all kinds of shape.