# Android code to make imageView round not working

Tags: android, xml, image, android-layout, imageview

I am trying to make my `ImageView` round. I have written the following code to make it appear round but somehow it is still showing square `ImageView`. [Using picasso to fetch image]

Java code:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) addLinkDialog.findViewById(R.id.group_icon_jsoup);
Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(GroupImageUrl).into(iv);
iv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_img);
```

ImageView code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/group_icon_jsoup"
    android:layout_width="75dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/icon_img" />
```

@drawable/icon_img.xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/circle"/>
</layer-list>
```

@drawable/circle.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="0dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thicknessRatio="1.9"
    android:useLevel="false" >
<solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

<stroke
    android:width="10dp"
    android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105775/imageview-in-circular-through-xml

Comment: @GaneshPatil I have taken code from the same place. It isnt working. May be because I am setting image using picasso.

Comment: try this one rounded image with picaso http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112150/android-create-circular-image-with-picasso

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17655264/how-to-add-a-shadow-and-a-border-on-circular-imageview-android?rq=1 or another approach would be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932805/cropping-circular-area-from-bitmap-in-android/28096369#28096369

Comment: @Srujan Barai do you want to do that without any library ;)

Comment: Have enough answers pointing to third party libraries. Would want to know why the code I have posted in question isnt working,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Major problem will be when you use Picasso to set image again to set to `imageView` view bounds not to the its background that you create.

If you programmatically set a one it will override your background!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false">
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

You can set this as background of your view.Then try to use `view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_img);` . you will notice the change!

You can go through [Add a background image to shape in xml Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002224/add-a-background-image-to-shape-in-xml-android)

[Mask ImageView with round corner background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527467/mask-imageview-with-round-corner-background)

to check the various ways people tried out here!

But with Picasso you can do this directly with out other 3rd parties.

```
  final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.group_icon_jsoup);
    Picasso.with(YourActivity.this).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png")
            .resize(100, 100)
            .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                    Bitmap imageBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                    RoundedBitmapDrawable imageDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(getResources(), imageBitmap);
                    imageDrawable.setCircular(true);
                    imageDrawable.setCornerRadius(Math.max(imageBitmap.getWidth(), imageBitmap.getHeight()) / 2.0f);
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(imageDrawable);
                }
                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.amanda);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Not perfect though. It is giving me a weird non circular border which is visible if I put a dark colour in parent layout. But that seems like a problem of pixel calculation in picasso library.  My image view wont take new images in a single activity lifecycle, so this would work for me as of now.

Comment: @Srujan Barai you can get a perfect solution using paint or by masking the image and your issue might be because the resize value on my example

Answer (score 4):

Why not using third party ?

Try this code

```
Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.add_image);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePicture);
imageView.setImageBitmap(getRoundedBitmap(picture));

 public Bitmap getRoundedBitmap(Bitmap bitmap){
        Bitmap circleBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setShader(shader);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        Canvas c = new Canvas(circleBitmap);
        c.drawCircle(bitmap.getWidth() / 2, bitmap.getHeight() / 2, bitmap.getWidth() / 2, paint);
        return circleBitmap;
    }
```

**Your xml file**

```
  <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgProfilePicture"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:civ_border_width="3dp"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/light_gray" />
```

and add this in **build.gradle**

```
 compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
```

**Cirular `ImageView` Done !**

[image]

Comment: I wanted to know what my code isnt working. Using a lib just to set imagview round, didnt seem good to me.

Comment: Why can't you use a 3rd party library? When it comes to legal standard the usage availablity depends significantly on the license provided by the developer of the 3rd party library.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to use only code or you are ok with library too? If you are ok with library may I suggest using [this](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) library, helped me a lot. If you don't want to use library, you can use RoundedBitmapDrawable:

```
RoundedBitmapDrawable drawable = 
       RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.getResources(), bitmap)

drawable.setCircular(true);
```

Use this drawable in your ImageView.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. But I would prefer not to use external libraries just to make imageView round.

Comment: @SrujanBarai Ok, give me few minutes I'll update the answer.

Comment: when the link is broken your answer has no value

Answer (score 1):

Hello @Surjan here is the code which help to create a image in Any shape which you want only you need image of your choice shape with transparent and combination of any other color, following was the  example :

```
protected Bitmap getPinnedImage(Bitmap original, int shapeImage) {
        if (original == null) {
            original = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_round_shape);
        }
        Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), shapeImage);

        original = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(original, mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(), true);

        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(mask.getWidth(), mask.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas mCanvas = new Canvas(result);

        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, null);
        mCanvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(null);
        return result;
    }
```

Here is the tow parameter first one is your original bitmap and second one is the your shape drawable, like following was the pin shape

[image]
now passing after this drawable you can get your image in pin shape no need to access any third party library.

Comment: I havent tried this I as already found a temporary solution to my problem. This seems to be a good solution but I havent worked with canvas much. Will use if I face issues with my current solution

Comment: Then no problem, But if you when  need in complex shape then you can use it, And Thanks for the votup.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) addLinkDialog.findViewById(R.id.group_icon_jsoup);

Picasso.with(getBaseContext()).load(GroupImageUrl).transform(new RoundedTransformation(5,15, Color.parseColor("#27a3cb"))).fit().into(iv);



public class RoundedTransformation implements Transformation {


private int mBorderSize;
private int mCornerRadius = 0;
private int mColor;

public RoundedTransformation(int borderSize, int color) {
    this.mBorderSize = borderSize;
    this.mColor = color;
}

public RoundedTransformation(int borderSize, int cornerRadius, int color) {
    this.mBorderSize = borderSize;
    this.mCornerRadius = cornerRadius;
    this.mColor = color;
}

@Override
public Bitmap transform(Bitmap source) {
    int width = source.getWidth();
    int height = source.getHeight();

    Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, source.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(image);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);


    if(this.mCornerRadius == 0) {
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
    }
    else {
        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(rect),this.mCornerRadius, this.mCornerRadius, paint);
    }

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode((PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)));
    canvas.drawBitmap(source, rect, rect, paint);

    Bitmap output;

    if(this.mBorderSize == 0) {
        output = image;
    }
    else {
        width = width + this.mBorderSize * 2;
        height = height + this.mBorderSize * 2;

        output = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, source.getConfig());
        canvas.setBitmap(output);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);

        rect = new Rect(0, 0, width, height);

        paint.setXfermode(null);
        paint.setColor(this.mColor);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        canvas.drawRoundRect(new RectF(rect), this.mCornerRadius, this.mCornerRadius, paint);

        canvas.drawBitmap(image, this.mBorderSize, this.mBorderSize, null);
    }

    if(source != output) source.recycle();

    return output;
}

@Override
public String key() {
    return "bitmapBorder(" +
            "borderSize=" + this.mBorderSize + ", " +
            "cornerRadius=" + this.mCornerRadius + ", " +
            "color=" + this.mColor +")";
}
```

}