# How to make a circular framelayout and capture a circular image using a custom camera API?

Tags: android, android-framelayout

I am working on one camera app and capturing image using custom camera api.
For preview I am using frame layout.I want to make that frame layout which is circular as shown in the image and show preview in circular frame layout.Please help.

[image]

Comment: you are having an imageView inside the framelayout?

Comment: @SamiKanafani no only frame layout for camera preview.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42083021/5156075

Comment: @JohnJoe that is imageview and if I am not wrong we can not show camera preview in image view.After capturing the image we can show captured image to image view.But my question is what about preview how to make it circular?For preview we can user surface layout or frame layout but challenge is making it circular.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15391329 may be this will help you. You can combine @John Joe answer and link content . Hop it will solve your problem.

Comment: @AshutoshSingh: Did you find a solution for this? I am stuck with the same implementation. Can you please post your solution. Thanks

Comment: No, I did not find solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

You want to change your view to circle, Right?

I found a library that can change your views to custom shapes.

link : https://github.com/florent37/ShapeOfView

```
    <com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.CircleView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"

        android:elevation="4dp"
        app:shape_circle_borderColor="@android:color/black"
        app:shape_circle_borderWidth="2dp">

            <!-- YOUR CONTENT -->

</com.github.florent37.shapeofview.shapes.CircleView>
```