# Android-Image-Cropper to circle

Tags: java, android, crop

I am trying to crop my images as a circle, for this I am using the provided library of Android-Image-Cropper - 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.4.+'  At the moment I am able to choose an image, the crop window appears as a circle, although it doesnt then crop to a circle but instead a square.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        CropImage.activity(imageUri)
                .setAspectRatio(150,150)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setCropShape(CropImageView.CropShape.OVAL)
                .start(this);
    }
    if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            mImageUri = result.getUri();
            mSetupImageBtn.setImageURI(mImageUri);
        } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
            Exception error = result.getError();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be easier to keep the image rectangular, and use Picasso with a circle transform whenever you display the image in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use glide for the same as mentioned in the first comment 
[How to round an image with Glide library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25278821/how-to-round-an-image-with-glide-library)

secondly, you can use the below library
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.2.1'

using Picasso you can use above circle image library ab can load image in it using picasso like this:

```
Picasso.with(activity).load(url).into(ImageView);
```

example :

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
                        android:id="@+id/img_profile"
                        android:layout_width="100dp"
                        android:layout_height="100dp" />



Picasso.with(activity).load(url).into(ImageView);
```

if you don't want to use circleImageView then you can create a transformation as used in this links comment

[android: create circular image with picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112150/android-create-circular-image-with-picasso)

Comment: ahh you know how i can do this with Picasso

Answer (score 0):

[ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper) **is not supported anymore** (read more [here](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/issues/858)). So you can migrate to a new project [CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper](https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper) which supports the circle crop function.

Example below:

Add `CropImageVIew` to your markup:

```
<com.canhub.cropper.CropImageView
    android:id="@+id/cropView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:cornerShape="rectangle" />
```

Setup image in the fragment or activity:

```
binding.cropView.setImageUriAsync(imageUri)
```

Add result listener to `cropView`:

```
binding.cropView.setOnCropImageCompleteListener { view, result ->
    //  !!! You should use result.getBitmap(ctx), because result.bitmap returns null !!!
    // Read more here: https://github.com/CanHub/Android-Image-Cropper/pull/70

    val imageBitmap = result.getBitmap(requireContext())!!
    val ovalBitmap = CropImage.toOvalBitmap(imageBitmap)

    // Now you can save ovalBitmap to file or set it to ImageView with setImageBitmap()
}
```

Add a click listener to your **"crop button"**:

```
binding.cropImageButton.setOnClickListener {
    binding.cropView.croppedImageAsync()
}
```