# Android Picasso, Unable to show image with HTTP URL

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android development, i tried using picasso and circularimageview combination, the problem is, the combo wont work whenever i refer to an image which is not from a secured url(HTTP)

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_userdataupdate);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.actionbargradient));

    CircularImageView civ = findViewById(R.id.profileImg);
    Picasso.get().load("http://chandra.harvard.edu/photo/2018/kes75/kes75_w11.jpg").transform(new CircleTransform()).into(civ);
    ImageView imgv = findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    Picasso.get().load("http://chandra.harvard.edu/photo/2018/kes75/kes75_w11.jpg").transform(new CircleTransform()).into(imgv);

}
```

Just to make sure its not a problem with circularimageview i tried imageview too.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/trialimage"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".userdataupdate">


<com.mikhaellopez.circularimageview.CircularImageView
    android:id="@+id/profileImg"
    android:layout_width="157dp"
    android:layout_height="144dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="122dp"
    app:civ_border_color="#EEEEEE"
    app:civ_border_width="4dp"
    app:civ_shadow="true"
    app:civ_shadow_color="#8BC34A"
    app:civ_shadow_radius="10" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="139dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars[1]" />
```

if i replace the src to any https image it works just fine.

Comment: Try This
Picasso.with(context).load("http://chandra.harvard.edu/photo/2018/kes75/kes75_w11.jpg").transform(new CircleTransform()).into(imgv);

Comment: You can try Glide too if you don't want to waste your time on looking for answer for your problem

Comment: i use the following version of picasso "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828" and it doesnt have 'with' function

Comment: Same issue with glide too

Comment: i tried your url with `with` function, it didn't work. i'm using version 2.5.2

Comment: Use picasso 2.5.2 version, and follow 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112150/android-create-circular-image-with-picasso

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi Guys appreciate your quick help and answers, figured out the issue is related to this post

[How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

Now it works fine.

Thanks