# Androidx CardView not showing the ccircular image as expected in all devices

Tags: android, cardview

I am using cardview to show the circular profile pic in my android. But it shows like some part is cut at the top and bottom in my emulator.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="134dp"
            android:layout_height="134dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@color/white_new"
            app:cardCornerRadius="100dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="134dp"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_height="134dp" />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Hi bro if you want circular image 2 ways 1.Recyle the image itself as circular using glide or picasso 2.Create mask as circular drawable apply to imageview but drawback is complete image wont show as circular it will look like circular you might lose corners of image.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112150/android-create-circular-image-with-picasso use this with picasso, works wonders

Comment: use this library work perfect: https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: Any workarounds with the same cardview